# Why is my loop returning the same value from a method that I am calling?

Tags: c#, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Random number generator only generating one random number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number)

My code below is doing this and I don't know why:

IF my toEmailAddresses array contains 2 e-mail addresses, `uniqueID[0]` and `uniqueID[1]` will return the same value generated from the `Util.CreateRandomPassword(16)` method call.

If I step through the code, then both `uniqueID[0]` and `uniqueID[1]` will contain different values like it should.  But if I run the code as usual, for some reason, the same value gets assigned to my `uniqueID` array:  `uniqueID[0]` and `uniqueID[1]` will contain the same value.

I even put in the `string tempRandomPassword = null` and then assign that to the value returned from the `CreateRandomPassword` method, but that does not work either.

What am I doing wrong?

```
//toEmailAddresses.Count array will have two e-mail addresses in it.

string[] uniqueID = new string[2];

for (int i = 0; i < toEmailAddresses.Count(); i++)
{
   string tempRandomPassword = null;
   tempRandomPassword = Util.CreateRandomPassword(16);

   uniqueID[i] = tempRandomPassword;
}


        public static string CreateRandomPassword(int passwordLength)
        {
            //http://madskristensen.net/post/Generate-random-password-in-C.aspx

            string allowedChars = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            char[] chars = new char[passwordLength];
            Random rd = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < passwordLength; i++)
            {
                chars[i] = allowedChars[rd.Next(0, allowedChars.Length)];
            }

            return new string(chars);
        }
```

Comment: Required reading: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx

Comment: `[c#] new Random duplicate` - search SO for this and read the documentation.

Comment: Soner, I would have no idea but if people down vote it has to be for a reason perhaps the answers that they provide are not correct or what the OP is looking for in terms of answering his question

Comment: Or someone's just a "funny guy"... doesn't seem to be wrong answers.

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih Although why answer at all with so many duplicates? :-/ (And why is this still open?)

Comment: I don't see any wrong answers at all .. I couldn't tell ya..

Comment: All three answers are exactly right. Someone either doesn't get this stuff, or just has a bad attitude.

Comment: @pst - this one is actually quite hard to analyze with a debugger.

Comment: @pst There were no other answers when I typed it up, but yeah a duplicate for sure.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Agreed. Even with years of experience this is an easy thing to overlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new instance of `Random` with the default seed on every invocation. If the seed is the same it will produce the same sequence of numbers. Store the instance and use that for all invocations.

Answer (score 1):

It is because your method uses

```
 Random rd = new Random();
```

This local instance of Random will auto-initialize using the clock but when two instances are created too close together (in time) they will use the same seed and produce the same random sequence.

As long as you're not calling this from multiple threads you can use a static field as a simple fix:

```
    private static Random _rd = new Random();

    public static string CreateRandomPassword(int passwordLength)
    {
        string allowedChars = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        char[] chars = new char[passwordLength];
        // Random rd = new Random();

        ...
    }
```

Comment: What do I do if I am calling it from multiple threads?

Comment: You'll need locking. The linked duplicate has a pretty good solution.

Comment: @fraXis http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your creating a new Random object each time, and since it uses time as a default seed, your getting the same seed, and thus the same numbers.

Make it a field of the class and only create it once.

This is why it worked when you stepped through it by the way. The extra time allowed the seed to change and return different results.

Answer (score -1):

Use thread sleep in the loop

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] uniqueID = new string[2];
            string[] toEmailAddresses = new string[2];
            toEmailAddresses[0] = "a@1.com";
            toEmailAddresses[1] = "b@1.com";

            for (int i = 0; i < toEmailAddresses.Count(); i++)
            {
                uniqueID[i] = CreateRandomPassword(16);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);               
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < uniqueID.Count(); i++)
                MessageBox.Show(i.ToString() + " : " + uniqueID[i]);
        }
```

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` is not a hammer, and `Random` is not a nail.